# Solving the matrix equation: $e^{\frac{1}{\ln(A)}}=A$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, trace

Looking to solve the matrix equation:
$$ e^{\frac{1}{\ln(A)}}=A $$

where $A$ is a matrix with a logarithm.

I am interested if this equation has a solution. I read about the logarithm of a matrix and the square root of a matrix. Still having trouble solving it though.

Comment: If $X^2=I$, then you can take $A=e^X$, assuming that the $\ln$ is defined such that $\ln(e^X)=X$ for that $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation does indeed have a solution:

Let's define $1=Id$ as the identity matrix.

First, take the natural logarithm of both sides to get $\frac{Id}{\log(A)}=\log(A).$

Next, multiply both sides by $\log(A).$ So, $Id=\log^2(A).$

$\log(A)=\begin{bmatrix}
    -1      & 0  \\
    0 &-1
\end{bmatrix}$

for $A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1/e      & 0  \\
    0 &1/e
\end{bmatrix}.$ So it follows that $\log^2(A)=Id.$

$\square$